# What are the various injectables in the link, controller and compile functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What objects can be passed as arguments to the link, controller and compile functions in AngularJS?

Comment: You should consider adding more information to your question.

If this really is all you're asking: [rtfm](http://docs.angularjs.org/)

Comment: I appreciate this question alot. b/c I am not very clever from the official doc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the information your looking for is available on AngularJS documentation website.

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }

function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }

function controller(scope, element, attribute, transcludeFn)
```

Look under Writing Directive Long Versions

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: The transclude parameter inside of the compile function is deperecated. Furthermore the link function has the translucdeFn as 5th parameter which should be used instead of deprecated translucde parameter in the compile function

Comment: So although both Jigar and Ilker's statements still hold true, I'm pretty sure the documentation has changed since the 2013.  The link function signature can be [found here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-).  The compile function signature can be [found here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-)